# Including Images in RenderPDF in Play Framework

Tags: pdf, playframework, playframework-1.x

I use Play framework 1.2.x

I use PDF module renderPDF to generate PDF from HTML. I would like insert a image into the PDF.

Im trying to download image from controller downloading in the HTML which will be render as PDF as like this

```
<img src="@{AwardController.getSignature()}">
```

From the forums I found that we need to define play.pool in application.conf, So I defined it and works well in local environment. But It doesn't work in QA or Prod environment where we have two processors, so I thought it would take nbprocessors+1. I tried both defining play.pool and not defining. But there is no luck in QA/Prod environment. Please help me to resolve

**UPDATE:** It working when http request, but not works in https request. Do we have any settings anywhere to resolved this

Comment: My own experience of this showed that making a HTTP call to get the image performs very poorly compared to writing the image to a temporary file, and then using a file:// URL in the PDF template.

Comment: Sounds possible the HTTPS call results in a redirect - have you profiled the call?

Comment: When a call to the server during PDF generation doesn't send any headers(It doesn't have cookies too). So it didn't get response. As this is internal call within the server I used http call to fetch the image

Comment: You should always get a response to a HTTP(S) call, even if it's a 401.  You need to check the response code you're getting, this will give you a starting point.  Also, check the request URL - there's a big difference between using localhost and the external address.